# Redux store does not update after dispatching an action to my reducer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Following problem: I've tried to write a generic typescript reducer the last few hours, and I feel like it's working fairly well already, but there's just one problem - They way I wired it with my store seems to have problems. It seems like the store does not properly update, as a component I tried to hook up with the data from the reducer does not receive new props.

This is the generic reducer. It's not fully complete yet, but the add functionality should work at least.

```
// Framework
import * as Redux from "redux";

// Functionality
import { CouldBeArray } from "data/commonTypes";
import { ensureArray } from "helper/arrayUtils";

type ReducerParams<T> = {
    actionIdentifier: string;
    key: keyof T;
}

export type ReducerState<T> = {
    data: Array<T>;
}

type ReducerAction<T> = Redux.Action & {
    payload: CouldBeArray<T>;
}

type Reducer<T> = {
    add: (data: T) => ReducerAction<T>;
    update: (data: T) => ReducerAction<T>;
    delete: (data: T) => ReducerAction<T>;
    replace: (data: T) => ReducerAction<T>;
    reducer: Redux.Reducer<ReducerState<T>, ReducerAction<T>>;
}

export const createReducer = <T>(params: ReducerParams<T>): Reducer<T> => {

    const ADD_IDENTIFIER = `${params.actionIdentifier}_ADD`;
    const UPDATE_IDENTIFIER = `${params.actionIdentifier}_UPDATE`;
    const DELETE_IDENTIFIER = `${params.actionIdentifier}_DELETE`;
    const REPLACE_IDENTIFIER = `${params.actionIdentifier}_REPLACE`;

    const initialState: ReducerState<T> = {
        data: []
    };

    const reducer = (state = initialState, action: ReducerAction<T>): ReducerState<T> => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case ADD_IDENTIFIER:
                const newState = { ...state };
                const newData = [ ...newState.data ];

                const payloadAsArray = ensureArray(action.payload);
                payloadAsArray.forEach(x => newData.push(x));

                newState.data = newData;
                return newState;
            case UPDATE_IDENTIFIER:
                return {
                    ...state,
                };
            case DELETE_IDENTIFIER:
                return {
                    ...state,
                };
            case REPLACE_IDENTIFIER:
                return {
                    ...state,
                };
            default:
                return initialState;
        }
    }

    const addAction = (data: T): ReducerAction<T> => {
        return {
            type: ADD_IDENTIFIER,
            payload: data,
        }
    };

    const updateAction = (data: T): ReducerAction<T> => {
        return {
            type: UPDATE_IDENTIFIER,
            payload: data,
        }
    };

    const deleteAction = (data: T): ReducerAction<T> => {
        return {
            type: DELETE_IDENTIFIER,
            payload: data,
        }
    };

    const replaceAction = (data: T): ReducerAction<T> => {
        return {
            type: REPLACE_IDENTIFIER,
            payload: data,
        }
    };

    return {
        add: addAction,
        update: updateAction,
        delete: deleteAction,
        replace: replaceAction,
        reducer: reducer,
    }
}
```

Next off, my store:

```
// Framework
import * as redux from "redux";

// Functionality
import { ReducerState } from "modules/common/Reducer/CrudReducer";

import { reducer as friendsReducer } from "modules/Friends/Reducer/FriendsReducer";
import { Friend } from "modules/Friends/types";

export type ReduxStore = {
    friendsReducer: ReducerState<Friend>;
}

export const store: ReduxStore = redux.createStore(
    redux.combineReducers({
        friendsReducer: friendsReducer.reducer,
    })
);

export default store;
```

and last but not least, the consuming component:

```
type Props = {
    friends: Array<Friend>
}

export const FriendsList: React.FC<Props> = ({ friends }) => {

    return (
        <Flex className={"FriendsList"}>
            Friends
        </Flex>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (store: ReduxStore): Props => {
    return {
        friends: store.friendsReducer.data,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(FriendsList);
```

The problem usually unfolds in the following order:

1. Data is properly fetched from network
2. Update the store via `store.dispatch(friendsReducer.add(payload))`
3. With the debugger, I did step through the genericreducer and saw that the new state properly contains the new data.
4. This is where the problem occurs - The freshly generated state by the reducer is not transferred to my Friendslist component. It will only receive props once, while the data in there is still empty.

Where did I go wrong?

EDIT: By demand, the code for the friendsReducer:

```
import { createReducer } from "modules/common/Reducer/CrudReducer";
import { Friend } from "modules/friends/types";

export const reducer = createReducer<Friend>({
    actionIdentifier: "FRIENDS",
    key: "id"
});

export default reducer;
```

and for the dispatch:

```
const friendsResponse = await friendsCommunication.getFriends();

if (friendsResponse.success){
    this.dispatch(friendsReducer.add(friendsResponse.payload));
}
```

...

```
protected dispatch(dispatchAction: Action){
    store.dispatch(dispatchAction);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using redux devtools? what are you getting in the switch statement just before you return? also I think updating the data can be like this? `const payloadAsArray = ensureArray(action.payload);
 return {
  ...state,
  data: [...state.data, ...payloadAsArray]
 }
`

Comment: `redux devtools` + `break point` would help your troubleshooting well enough in my opinion.

Comment: @MonteCristo The new state looks about right, the new data is added.

Comment: @keikai I did take a look at the redux devtools, although I don't have too much experience with it. What I find a bit odd is that the state of the next action (After the FRIENDS_ADD in my case) shows that the state of the friendsReducer is empty again.

Comment: Could you also add `friendsReducer` code? show how you create it? Also the code that's dispatching the action. you can also try adding [redux logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-logger) and trace the actions/states being passed. You can also create [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) and choose import or `react+ts` template. So then would be easier for us to take a look.

Comment: @MonteCristo I added the code for now, I think creating a sandbox is a bit more difficult with all the code I would need to add. Maybe this already helps with tracing the problem. Thanks already for helping, though.

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are importing the `FriendsList` component?  Because you export both the plain component and the redux-connected one, you have to make sure you are importing the default export `import FriendsList` and not the plain one `import { FriendsList }`

Comment: @MatthewG It's properly importing import FriendsList from "modules/Friends/Components/FriendsList";, I'm also getting initial redux props, just not the correct one (Only empty ones)

Comment: I was able to debug a bit further now, and I found out that ANY action, no matter for which sub-reducer, resets all current reducer's data.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - My generic reducer returned the following as default:

```
  default:
       return initialState;
```

while it should return `state`.

Otherwise it just did reset the state of all iterated reducers for every action.